# How to scrape info off this interactive website

Tags: web-scraping

I am having some trouble being able to pick up data on the following website: https://www.cms.gov/Research-Statistics-Data-and-Systems/Statistics-Trends-and-Reports/Dashboard/Medicare-Drug-Spending/Drug_Spending_Dashboard.html

It's interactive nature makes it difficult for me to do, but I really just want the first table you see with the different drug names. I am tried inspecting different elements in Chrome to try to find the data source, but I cannot find any raw files. Any ideas how I could approach this problem?

Comment: This is a flash site. Have a look into this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223624/can-i-scrape-flash

Comment: It's a flash plugin.. maybe this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17075555/5374294

Comment: This SO question also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985474/scraping-flash-websites?rq=1